# ¿Cómo reemplazar múltiples saltos de línea por un string vacío?

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2013

Tengo un gran archivo .csv el cual está separado por comas y rodeado de doble comillas entre cada una de las columnas.

En una de las columnas tengo largo contenido de texto y este tiene varios saltos de líneas.
Lo que requiero hacer es poder remplazar estos saltos de líneas y alinear bien el texto.

Esto es lo que intentado de hacer:

```
string archivo = File.ReadAllText(FileName); //camino donde esta mi archivo
//archivo = archivo.Replace(@"\n", @""); // primer intento, pero nada cambia
//Regex.Replace(archivo, @"\n\n", ""); //segundo intento, pero mismo resultado
//archivo = archivo.Replace(@"\t|\n|\r", @""); //tercer intento, pero mismo resultado
//archivo.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""); //cuarto intento, pero mismo resultado
//archivo = archivo.Replace("\n", String.Empty); //quinto intento, pero mismo resultado
```

Comment: Haz probado con `archivo = archivo.Replace("pon dos espacios", "pon un solo espacio"); `  ?  Quitara casi todos los espacios.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el último de tus intentos no reemplaza nada??? Debería devolverte todo el texto en una única línea, sin saltos de línea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ya veo el fallo

No escribes los cambios en el archivo y no sustituyes de la forma correcta

```
public void Reemplazar(string ruta)
        {
            try
            {
                string contenido = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ruta);
                string reemplazo = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(contenido, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ruta, reemplazo); // OJO, escribes los cambios en el archivo
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Y lo llamas asi:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string link = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\\Prueba.csv"; // ruta de ejemplo
            Reemplazar(link);
        }
```